# Await n-th OnNext() of Observable

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I've got an observable that calls `OnNext()` a bunch of times. I would like `await` the moment the `OnNext` argument meets a certain criteria. How can I do that?

It's almost like the example in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) post where a Process execution is awaited:

```
public static TaskAwaiter<int> GetAwaiter(this Process process) 
{ 
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(); 
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
    process.Exited += (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(process.ExitCode); 
    if (process.HasExited) tcs.TrySetResult(process.ExitCode); 
    return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter(); 
}
```

So let me get into the code: my colleague wrote a bus implementation which simplified looks like this:

```
public class MyBus : IObservable<MessageRecieved>
{
    public void Post(IBusMessage message)
    {
        foreach (var observer in this.observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(new MessageRecieved(message.GetType(), MessageRecieved.MessageStage.Recieved));
        }

        message.Handle();

        foreach (var observer in this.observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(new MessageRecieved(message.GetType(), MessageRecieved.MessageStage.Handled));
        }
    }
    // ... some more stuff
}
```

What happens is that a message is posted, which does something with the message and then posts a new message on the bus. So a series of messages is posted on the bus, which are then handled. The actual implementation is a bit different and uses messagehandlers and stuff, but that's not relevant to the question.

Problem is: we need to know when it's finished. I know the messagetype of the final message ( Let's say `LastMessageType` ). So my idea was to make that bus implement `IObservable` and create an `Observer` that collects events and raises an event when a message is caught with the type `LastMessageType`.

However, I've seen Bart de Smet await a random series of events (windows forms events) and create an awaiter for that. So what I would like to do is have something like:

```
var initialMessage = ConstructInitialMessage();
var bus = new MessageBus();
await bus.Process(initialMessage);
```

Can someone point me in a direction where to find a solution for this. I've implemented an observer that raises an event in case OnNext catches a `LastMessageType` message, but it wasn't awaitable. Like so:

```
public static TaskAwaiter<int> ProcessMessage(this MyBus bus, BeginMessage message)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    var observcer = new MessageObserver();
    observcer.LastMessageRecieved += () => tcs.SetResult(1);
    return tcs.Task.GetAwaiter();
}
```

Comment: You're not implementing `IObservable<T>` yourself, are you? Because there is no use case where that's ever recommended.

Comment: @StephenCleary - You mean whether or not I used the BCL IObservable ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx ) ? Yes I did. Why isn't that good? Can you point me to a resource that explains why I shouldn't have done that?

Comment: Yes; the example code on that page is completely wrong. `IObservable<T>` has specific threading requirements which that example code completely ignores. The [Rx design guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/10/28/rx-design-guidelines.aspx) (section 6) indirectly states that you shouldn't implement that interface yourself.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Very interesting ... thanks! I also considered using Reactive Extensions. So what I could do is raise events on the Post of the bus and use Rx to do something in case the `FinalMessageType` is posted.

Comment: @spike I think that it doesn't make much sense to use `IObservable` without Rx, it's significantly more useful with it.

Comment: **Task.GetAwaiter Method :** This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code.

Answer (score 2):

> So what I would like to do is have something like:
>
> ```
> await bus.Process(initialMessage);
> ```

You *can* do that, using Rx (after you reference it from your project, add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`). What this does is to wait until the observable completes (calls `OnCompleted` on its observers).

If for some reason you can't fix the observable to complete properly, you will have to create a new observable that ends when the original one should. To do that, you can use `FirstAsync()` with a predicate:

```
await bus.Process(initialMessage).FirstAsync(
    message => message.Type == finalType 
        && message.Stage == MessageRecieved.MessageStage.Handled);
```

> I've implemented an observer […] but it wasn't awaitable.

The problem with that code is that your code returns the `TaskAwaiter<int>`. `TaskAwaiter` is not awaitable, `Task` itself is. So, if you change your code to just `return tcs.Task;` and change the return type, it should work.

Comment: I'll give this a try - awesome!